Optimizing Daily Retrieval of Latest Loan ConditionDate from Large Table
I have a table called "dbo.Loans" that stores loan information, including calculated columns showing the remaining loan amount for each day, from the loan's start date to its end date. The "LoanName" column may have duplicate values for different entries. The "ConditionDate" column indicates the date for which we want to check loan information.
My goal is to retrieve the most recent "ConditionDate" for each "LoanName". Typically, the most recent "ConditionDate" corresponds to the loan's end date (when the loan is fully paid off, often ahead of schedule).
The SQL job should run daily to fetch the latest "ConditionDate" for each "LoanName". However, since the table contains around 500 million rows, running this query daily is challenging in terms of performance, even though the table is well indexed.
I am looking for ways to further optimize this process.
SELECT LoanName, MAX(ConditionDate) as ConditionDate
FROM dbo.Loans
WHERE ConditionDate >= '20180101' 
GROUP BY LoanName


This question would benefit if you add sample data and expected outcome, but please not as an image but as text

even though the table is well indexed it would also help if you can show us the table schema and all present indexes.

If you are running this daily then presumably the vast majority of loans will have unchanged results from previous day. Do you really need this for all loans from the last 6+ years?

We can't guess the table schema or indexes. Generating reports over transactional tables is inefficient to begin with. Reporting is usually performed using separate reporting databases or data warehouses with schemas specifically designed to make reporting easier. In a reporting schema the latest ConditionDate would be an extra column updated through an ETL job

As for aggregating a 500M row table, a columnstore index would improve performance and reduce storage by only storing individual values, like a columnstore database.

On top of that, as Martin Smith said, those dates don't change every day. You could calculate and update only the changed ones if you use a Modified column or Change Tracking to find the rows changed since the last run and only update the MaxConditionDate for the changed columns.

I wanted something like Martin Smith said, how to find the rows changed since the last run and update only changed ones?

You mentioned that the table is well indexed.  The index you probably want here is:
CREATE INDEX idx ON dbo.Loans (LoanName, ConditionDate);

In fact, the above index should actually be a covering index, meaning that this index alone can be scanned to satisfy the entire query.  If you don't already have this index on your table, you should try adding it and then check the performance.

Perhaps ConditionDate descending so the most-recent is first?
